# What is the sum of the squares of roots of the equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the sum of the squares of roots of the equation below?

$$m^{1/3} + ( 2m-3)^{1/3} =  \big(12 ( m –  1)\big)^{1/3}$$

Comment: I tried to solve it . But the equation become very complicated .  729m^3 - 2727m^2 + 3294m -1331 = 0 .

Comment: The sum of squares of the roots of $x^3+a x^2+b x + c$ is $a^2 - 2b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the roots $a,b,c$. From the equation in your comment, do you know how to get $a+b+c$? do you know how to get $ab+ac+bc$? can you work out how to get $a^2+b^2+c^2$, if you know $a+b+c$ and $ab+ac+bc$?

Comment: Thabks Gerry.Got your answer. But the value is not coming as integer.  I think i have done the solution wrong.

Comment: Do you have some reason to think the answer is an integer?